# int number; number.m_value?

Tags: visual-studio

Today my Visual studio couldn't help me by auto complete so I thought that the ReSharper trial period had ended .After I suspended ReSharper I see that still no auto complete. After a few changes I see still the same problem and there are some strange behavior in Visual Studio. For example I see m_value field for int. But my other Visual studio instances works as expected. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file property build action was content and this was reason of those strange behaviours. It is fixed after turned build action to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is an error somewhere in your code which is causing the types to be determined incorrectly - for example a missing curly brace. Check your code carefully for errors. Make sure that your code compiles correctly.

PS: You don't need ReSharper to get autocompletion. [Intellisense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) is a standard feature of Visual Studio. Even without ReSharper I find the built-in autocompletion extremely usable.

> IntelliSense is Microsoft's implementation of autocompletion, best known for its use in the Microsoft Visual Studio integrated development environment.

Comment: Thank u. You gave me hint that where it can cause and now i found it.